# How to update the local json field in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and dart I read a lot of web article and documentation but didn't able to figure out how to update JSON field I have a local JSON file like

```
 {
"category": "Happiness",
"quotes":[
  {
  "quote":"I hope you will find a reason to smile",
  "favorite":false
  },
  {
  "quote":"Sometimes your joy is the source of your smile, but sometimes your smile can be the source of your joy.",
  "favorite":false
  }]}
```

I want to update the filed favorite to true in JSON file  Is there any way to do this

Answer (score 2):

You Can parse the JSON like this

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonString);
```

And if you want to make each favorite true then You can use looping like this

```
(data["quotes"] as List<dynamic>).forEach((item) => item["favorite"] = true);
```

if you want to set a single object value `true` then you need to pass the `position` like this

```
(data["quotes"] as List<dynamic>)[position]['favorite'] = true;
```

**Addition**

[Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) is the link to encode and decode the JSON

Comment: Yes it will update the field and then you can convert data map into the JSON file

Comment: Yes you need to fetch the json from the file into the string variable and then use above code to update and then write the same json into the same file again.

Comment: I want to change in json file like if i click button then specific index favorite's filed change to true..

Comment: i need to load whole json file for each click

Answer (score 0):

You can use a forEach loop on  the `quotes` list in the JSON and set `favourite` to `true` inside it. I'm assuming you have a parsed your `String` data into JSON using `jsonDecode` or `json.decode`.

If not, here's a [link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51) on how to parse JSON data in Dart.

Consider the below code -

```
Map<String, dynamic> jsonData =  {
    "category": "Happiness",
    "quotes":[
     {
          "quote":"I hope you will find a reason to smile",
          "favorite":false
     },
     {
          "quote":"Sometimes your joy is the source of your smile, but sometimes your smile can be the source of your joy.",
          "favorite":false
     }
]};

(jsonData["quotes"] as List<dynamic>).forEach((item) {
    item["favorite"] = true;
});
```

You can also alternatively use shorthand syntax for the `forEach` loop function like below -

```
(jsonData["quotes"] as List<dynamic>).forEach((item) => item["favorite"] = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

first take this json array to any variable and then understand the hierarchy .

e.g "jsonArr" is the array that hold that data then ..

jsonArr['quotes'][0]['favorite'] = true;

or you can put this in a for loop and traverse this loop to the length of the json array.

Comment: I want to change in json file like if i click button then specific index favorite's filed change to true..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method. The field `favorite` is changed to `true` when the button is pressed.

```
FlatButton(
    child: Text('Add Favourite'),
    onPressed: (){
         myJson['quotes'][myIndex]['favorite'] = true;
})
```